# How to use "Some more so than others"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, sentence, sentence-meaning

Consider the following sentence:

> Americans all around the world felt a sense of pride, some more so than others.

Is such a usage of the phrase correct?

Comment: The concessive nature of 'some more so than others' seems out of place after the patriotic 'Americans all around the world felt a sense of pride'. And 'some more than others' is generally preferred to 'some more so than others'.

Comment: Results from Google include "People in online games are toxic, some more so than others." "All research contributions are equal: some more so than others." "These following Etudes are admittedly ridiculous to play through; some more so than others." Not quite sure what these all have in common, but there seems an attempt to downplay certain parts of the set: all are bad but some are worse, or all have some X but some only have a little X.

Comment: The "so" in the examples from @StuartF refers back to the predicate adjective: "more so" = "more toxic", "more equal", "more ridiculous to play through". OP's sentence doesn't have a predicate adjective, and I think that's why Edwin Ashworth deprecated "so" in that case.